# Renaming active workbook in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rename

Is there a way to rename an active workbook in VBA?  The workbook name (MTD_Truck_October2017.xls) will change every month I run a big macro on, and it references the name at one point.  I'd like to rename it at the beginning to say MTD_Truck_Current.xls, then I can reference that name which will then be consistent for every month.

Also, the macro will need to run on several users computers.  I originally just saved to my desktop as a certain name, but now that others will be using this, the path to their desktop is different, so I either rename the workbook at the beginning, or I have to change the path in the macro for every user.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Workbook name is the read only property, you cannot change it. Though you can save it with a different name. Why don't you use the Environ Function to construct the path to desktop so that it will refer to the path to each individual user's desktop. Try Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\<Your file name here.xls>"

Comment: Post the parts of the code that open the file, and the part that references the workbook later, and we can help you fix your issue.

Comment: @12fretter You've asked quite a few questions recently, but haven't yet accepted any answers. How 'bout going back through the questions you've asked, and accepting those answers that best address your problem? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The workbook that holds a macro can be referred to as ThisWorkbook. It has a path and Name property. Rather than hold the name of the workbook as anything, use

```
ThisWorkbook.Name
```

Comment: That would work in a lot of cases, but in this case, one of the things I'm trying to accomplish is clean up.  Once I filter one file into a list of advisors, that list is copied and pasted into another workbook.  Then I want to go back to that file and delete it.  But when you select the active workbook, in the macro, it has to reference the name as you select it.  I don't think this will work.  

I also tried copying the data I want, then while still active, closing without saving the file, but then the paste into the new workbook does not work.